# Making A Scrollable Centered Navigation On Smaller Devices Using Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have the standard Bootstrap navbar with `class="justify-content-center"`. I want this navbar to be scrollable as soon as the elements have not enough space. My problem is that, I can only scroll to the right but not to the left. The following codes that I've been using is located at https://jsfiddle.net/rwx0xLm8/.

Comment: Need you position to be relative? Put it inside an absolute container or put position absolute directly in .nav

Comment: @Sam If I set the .nav to `position:absolute;`the whole nav is aligned to the left, but I want it to be in the center...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it mate.

```
  <div class="container-fluid" style="width:100%">

      <div class="row justify-content-center">

         <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab 4</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab 5</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab 6</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab 7</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab 8</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab 9</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab 10</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab 11</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab 12</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab 13</a></li>
        </ul>      
     </div>
</div>


.nav {

  overflow:auto; 
  text
}
.nav .nav-item a {white-space: nowrap;}
```

Comment: No worries. See, check this place http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/ you can play a little and get more used with flex-boxes properties.